# popup is shown before click-event is executed

Tags: javascript, html

I tried to use a menu-bar example I found at webdesign.tutsplus.com.

(http://webdesign.tutsplus.com/articles/create-a-quick-sticky-menu--webdesign-12120)

My problem is, that my popup is loaded directly after the page is loaded - but I just want this to happen when I click on one of my menu-items.

I thought removing `$(document).ready` would do the trick - but it did not...

The Popup:

```
 <div class="popup">
    <div class="arrow"></div>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="">List Item 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="">List Item 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="">List Item 3</a></li>
        </ul>
 </div>
```

Javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

 $(document).ready(
    function(){
    $("#support").click(function () {
        $(".popup").fadeToggle(150);
        return false;
    });
});

</script>
```

CSS

```
div.popup{
display: none;
float: right;
position: relative;
left: 5%;
background-color: #2C3E50;
-webkit-border-radius: .2em;
-moz-border-radius: .2em;
border-radius: .2em;
}

div.popup ul li a{
position: relative;
display: inline-block;
font-size: .85em;
color: #fff;
padding: 0 2em 0 2em;
margin: .4em;
text-align: center;
text-decoration: none;
transition: all 0.1s ease-in-out;
-webkit-border-radius: .2em;
-moz-border-radius: .2em;
border-radius: .2em;
}

div.popup ul li a:hover{
background-color: #1ABC9C;
}
```

Thank you,
Chris

Comment: There's nothing in that code that would trigger the popup on page load. Something else must be happening. Are you hiding `.popup` properly with CSS?

Comment: I just added the CSS.

Comment: Everything you've posted looks fine. Consider putting your example in a fiddle so we can see the problem. http://jsfiddle.net

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only guess I can make from your code is you might have missed some CSS rules. Please check the following, Did you hide the popup element in your css.

STEP-8 of tutorial

```
div.popup{
    display: none;
    /* Other styles */
}
```

This might fix your problem.

**EDIT**

Here is a fiddle demonstrating your Code. Your code has no errors but some allignment issues. Everything is working fine. Did you add the JQuery library. Check this fiddle.

http://jsfiddle.net/9Gfbb/

Answer (score 0):

To make sure, you can do this to your code.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".popup").hide();  // hide the popup in the case, that it wasn't hidden.
  $("#support").click(function () {
    $(".popup").fadeToggle(150);
    return false;
  });
});
```